# jvector map markers are not showing up properly

Tags: jquery, maps, jvectormap

I am using [JVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) to display the map of United States and wanted to place markers on 5 cities.  I have their Longitude and Latitude in my code but it seems to not work.  I see the marker in the upper left hand corner of the map.  I am not sure why they are positioned there, instead of on the cities I have in my code?

If anyone can provide some insight as to why the markers are not working properly:

See my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtian/fqqGs/

JS:

```
$(function(){
        $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'us_aea_en',
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        markerStyle: {
          initial: {
            fill: '#F8E23B',
            stroke: '#383f47'
          }
        },
        markers: [
          {latLng: [41.50, 87.37], name: 'Chicago'},
          {latLng: [32.46, 96.46], name: 'Dallas'},
          {latLng: [36.10, 115.12], name: 'Las Vegas'},
          {latLng: [34.3, 118.15], name: 'Los Angeles'},
          {latLng: [40.43, 74.00], name: 'New York City'}
        ]        
        });
       });​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just provided wrong coordinates. Longitude should be negative:

```
markers: [
    {latLng: [41.50, -87.37], name: 'Chicago'},
    {latLng: [32.46, -96.46], name: 'Dallas'},
    {latLng: [36.10, -115.12], name: 'Las Vegas'},
    {latLng: [34.3, -118.15], name: 'Los Angeles'},
    {latLng: [40.43, -74.00], name: 'New York City'}
]
```

Here is an updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fqqGs/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your "grid"? something like this?

```
$.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'map_name',{ 
"insets": [{
    "width": 500, 
    "top": 0, 
    "height": 500, 
    "bbox": [{
        "y": -12000000.0, 
        "x": -19000000.0
    }, {
        "y": 6900000.0, 
        "x": 19000000.0
    }],
}],
"paths": {
...
```

Comment: The map was ok, the problem was in coordinates of the cities.